# Trying to get session from http response in Angular 2

Tags: http, session, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 2 app which runs on port 8000 on the lite server. My express app (back-end) runs on port 3000.

When I send my credentials to the back-end which runs on port 3000, then I can see that I had succesfully logged in on port 8000. But I don't get a session as a response from the back-end. Here is a screenshot of it link:

[image]

As you can see the response says `Session not found`.

And when I succesfully log in on port 3000. Then I do get a session as response from the back-end. Here is a screenshot of it link:

[image]

Also here is a screenshot of logging in on port 3000 through Postman (Rest client) link:

[image]
And here is a screenshot of getting a session as a response on port 3000 link:

[image]

So now I can conclude that there is no problem at the back-end.

My question is: how can I also get the session as a response on port 8000?

Here is my code:

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
    //On page refresh the constructor gets called
    constructor(private _userService: UserService) {

        this._userService.getSession()
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    console.log("app session ");
                    //log the response which shows a session
                    console.log(res); 
                },
                error => {
                    console.log("app session error");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
    }
}
```

login.component.ts:

```
export class LoginComponent {
    user: User = new User();
    loginRes: String;
    private toasterService: ToasterService;

    public toasterconfig: ToasterConfig = new ToasterConfig({
        showCloseButton: true,
        tapToDismiss: false,
        timeout: 0
    });

    constructor(private _userService: UserService, toasterService: ToasterService, private router: Router) {
        this.toasterService = toasterService;
    }

    data = {};
    onSubmit() {
        this._userService.login(this.user)
            .subscribe(
                //we are using an arrow function here
                res => {            
                    this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Success', 'You have logged in ' + res.username);
//                  I don't use navigate(), because I want a redirect where the page gets refreshed
//                  this.router.navigate(['/']); 
                    var host = location.host;
                    console.log("host");
                    console.log(host);
                    //redirects where the page also gets refreshed
                    window.location.href = "http://"+ host;
                },
                error => {
                     this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Failed', error._body);
                }
            );
    }
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private url: string;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

    login(user: User) {
        this.url = config.getEnvironmentVariable('endPoint')+'api/auth/login';
        let data = { "username": user.username, "password": user.password };
        let body = JSON.stringify(data);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        console.log("login url " + this.url);
        return this._http.post(this.url, body, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getSession() {
        this.url = config.getEnvironmentVariable('endPoint')+'api/auth/';
        console.log("session url " + this.url);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        options.body = '';

        return this._http.get(this.url, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    } 

    private handleError(error: any) {
        //the Observable catches and throws an error
        return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Comment: you may need to enable CORS on your API

Comment: @MadhuRanjan my CORS is already enabled. I have already write the code for it in my Express app. Also if this was the case, then I shouldn't been able to log in from the Angular 2 app into the Express app.

Comment: Can you show us the controller method you are calling on the Express side?  Might be helpful to know how it's processing it

Comment: @DaveV I don't think there is a problem with the controller. But if you want to see it, then here is the link to it: http://pastebin.com/tkyuWBX9

Comment: I wonder if it isn't something to do with the sessions not matching up.  You are attaching the user data to the request session.  I've not done much with storing a session on the express side, but I know PassportJS does it own serialize and deserialize to store the session.  Could it be that when you make the getSession call after logging in, you are in fact getting a different session (since it's a different request)?  I'm kind of new to this part of the stack so forgive me if I'm being naive.

Comment: @DaveV Somehow the session is empty even after I had log in on port 8000. Also it doesn't matter wether it's a different request. Because all requests are sent to the Express app on port 3000.